# set a plotyy function vs text in matlab

Tags: matlab, textlabel

I need to plot two sets of data on separate y axis and plot them vs an x that is text

```
y1 = 

    0.0217545037216382
    0.0218522372528616
    0.00848250610252238
    0.00631477252766555
    0.00836543852985331
    0.00404498017959712
    0.0111088524041279
    0.0137053885611881
    0.0127748811974527
    0.0127058407416728

y2= [3,3,3,4,5,4,5,4,3,4]

x={'AU10','WI11','SP11','AU11','WI12','SP12','AU12','SP13','AU13','SP14']
```

I couldn't plot vs text so I created

```
x2=[1:10]

plotyy(x2,y1,x2,y2)
```

then to change `x` to the text I used

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',x);
```

but the problem is the 1:10 labels are still there underneath the text labels so I tried removing the labels with

```
set(gca,'XTick',[])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[])
```

and

```
set(gca,'Ticklength',[0 0])
```

also tried replacing with this

```
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',x, 'XTick',1:numel(x))
```

but the 1:10 string is still there underneath the text string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because `plotty` creates *two* axes. When you do `set(gca,'XTickLabel',x);` you are affecting only one of those axes (`gca` refers to only one axis, probably the one that was created last).

Solution:

1. Get handles to the two axes

   ```
   h = plotyy(x2,y1,x2,y2);
   ```

   (check that `h` is a 1x2 vector of handles)
2. Set the `'Xticklabel'` property of both axes to the desired labels:

   ```
   set(h,'XTickLabel',x);
   ```

   Alternatively, set `'Xticklabel'` of one of the axes to the desired labels, and for the other axis set it to `[]` (no labels):

   ```
   set(h(1),'XTickLabel',x);
   set(h(2),'Xticklabel',[])
   ```